# Can I programmatically access songs in a PLA android playlist with C#?

Tags: c#, android, windows, playlists

In Windows 8.1 when you look at the contents of an android device with the file explorer, right click on a playlist, then click properties, you can view the songs in the playlist in the 'References' tab.

Is it possible to write C# code to open a .PLA file and print out the songs in that playlist?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this a while ago but it was difficult to find details: I found the following though:

- the binary .pla file is working with 8 byte "words"; the first one is header, with file count in second byte.
- now, there's only 8 byte record for each file in the playlist.

I suspect it's a index directly to FAT.

First of all, renaming the file didn't render the playlist useless; even moving the whole structure of folders one up didn't do any damage (so I can create .pla files using your program and then bump everything up and have my single-level structure). -

Here is a format of the .pla file:

8 byte – header of the file:
2 byte – number of records
2 byte - interval in sec (for slideshow), 00 01 для for playlist
4 byte - 00 00 00 00

8 byte – per each record:
2 byte - 01 01 – card memory, 02 00 – phone memory
2 byte – last record’s (LFN-record) index of file in the folder
4 byte – folder’s sector number